# Properties not able to extract from JMS message through QueueBrowser

Tags: jms, websphere-6.1

Just to elaborate, we are not seeing JMS application properties in the message though the JMS system properties are showing up in the newly create MQ 7 queues.  The steps to recreate the error for understanding

Working Scenario

1. Create a new JMS message
2. Set the application properties in this JMS message using setStringProperty API call
3. Drop the message to migrated queue MQ 7 (from MQ 6 to MQ 7 queue)
4. Go to UI, browse the message through JMS QueueBrowser
5. Able to see all the application properties

Not working Scenario

1. Create a new JMS message
2. Set the application properties in this JMS message using setStringProperty API call
3. Drop the message to newly create MQ 7 queue
4. Go to UI, browse the message through JMS QueueBrowser
5. Not able to see all the application properties though we can see the JMS system properties ( JMS_IBM*)

We took the dump of message from the newly created queue. We see the application properties in the message dump.  But when we extract the message through api 
Enumeration messageEnum = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();

enumeration list messages which doesn’t show application properties in all the messages  for the newly created queue. But same API can extract the message with application properties for the migrated queues.

We are using websphere application server v 6.1 and Websphere MQ 7.0.1.6.

Could you please explain what I am doing wrong?